# Cannot export Firebase data to bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to follow this [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/move-data) to transfer data between two Firebase instances. However, I keep running into the following error in the GCP terminal:

```
gsutil iam ch serviceAccount:museo-e66b5@appspot.gserviceaccount.com:admin gs://sample_01
> 403 me@me.com does not have storage.buckets.getIamPolicy access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.
```

I've assigned the user roles with this permission, however, the policy editor indicates that I do not have permission to make the API call:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "role": "roles/firebase.managementServiceAgent", // Permission is in role
      "members": [
        "serviceAccount:firebase-service-account@firebase-sa-management.iam.gserviceaccount.com", // 
        "serviceAccount:service-shh@gcp-sa-firebase.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
      ]
    },
    {
      "role": "roles/firebasestorage.serviceAgent", // Permission is in role
      "members": [
        "serviceAccount:service-shh@gcp-sa-firebasestorage.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
      ]
    },
    {
      "role": "roles/storage.admin", // Permission is in role
      "members": [
        "user:me@me.com" // Principal matches
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I've tried creating a custom role with this permission explicitly assigned. I've also tried going adding `roles/firebasestorage.serviceAgent` and `roles/firebasestorage.serviceAgent`  in the IAM editor, but I'm restricted from adding them to non service accounts.

Comment: `me@me.com` needs to have `storage.objectAdmin` (though `storage.admin` is greater and fine too) on the bucket itself or the project containing the bucket. Because you're getting the error, it seems that `sample_01`  isn't in the project on which you're applying the policy.

Comment: Yep, sample_01 was not. You are correct.

Comment: @DazWilkin Coming from AWS, and I feel like this error message could be a bit more informative. Though, at the same time, I kind of understand why it shouldn't be from a security perspective. What do you think?

Comment: IIRC Cloud Storage was the 2nd GCP service after App Engine. Both continue to have some differences as a result. You (still) can't use `gcloud` for GCS but must use `gsutil` which is quirky enough. IAM was also layered onto GCP after many services (including GCS) were available. GCS Buckets, even though (as all GCP resources) scoped to Projects appear challenged to infer the Project and I suspect some combination of all of this means that `gsutil` can't be more helpful in identifying the project to offer a more comprehensive error.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your bucket names, `gs://sample_01` was not in my project.

Comment: To be clear, it's **not** that `gs://sample_01` was "not in my project", all buckets are in a project, it's that your identity had insufficient permissions on the bucket (either directly or indirectly through the project) to grant the `storage.admin` role.

Comment: No, that bucket actually did not exist haha anywhere. It was a typo. I just didn't realize it because the error message wasn't clear.